# Javascript with html

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 combobox one depend on another combobox,say in 1st combobox mobile and Tv is there and when mobile is selected in combobox 1 then Onida, Samsung should be automatically populated in combobox 2.and when Onida is selected its rate should be automatically shown in a textbox .

When Tv is selected in Combobox 1 means same Onida and Samsung should be Populated in Combobox 2 on selecting Onida the rate of Tv onida company should be displayed in textbox.

Thus Onida and Samsung will be same for combobox1 either it may be Mobile or Tv only the rates should be varied according to first selection combobox whether it is Mobile or Tv it depends.

How to do in Javascript and html.
I tried out but im not getting.

In above code only second combobox i brought i dont know to bring 1 combobox respective to 2nd combox box and display its rate.

**EDIT:**

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT"> 
function calc() { 
    var inp = document.reals.inpt.value;
    var func = document.reals.functn.value;
    var outp = 0;
    if (func == 'Onida') {
        outp =1275
    }
    if (func == 'Samsung') {
        outp = 925
    } 
    document.reals.outpt.value = outp; 
} 
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD> 
<BODY> 
    <FORM ACTION="#" NAME="reals"> 
    <INPUT TYPE=Hidden NAME="inpt" SIZE=10 VALUE="0">
    <SELECT NAME="functn" ONCHANGE="calc()">
        <OPTION>- please select -</OPTION> 
        <OPTION VALUE="onida">onida</OPTION> 
        <OPTION VALUE="Samsung">Samsung</OPTION>
    </SELECT> 
    <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="outpt" SIZE=10 DISABLED>
```

Comment: Can you post your code attempt?

Comment: Can u share the code u tried.

Comment: <SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">


function calc() {
  var inp = document.reals.inpt.value
  var func = document.reals.functn.value
  var outp = 0

  if (func == 'Onida') {outp =1275}
  if (func == 'Samsung') {outp = 925}
 
  
  document.reals.outpt.value = outp
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM ACTION="#" NAME="reals">
<INPUT TYPE=Hidden NAME="inpt" SIZE=10 VALUE="0">
<SELECT NAME="functn" ONCHANGE="calc()">
<OPTION>- please select -</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="onida">onida</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="Samsung">Samsung</OPTION>


</SELECT>
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="outpt" SIZE=10 DISABLED>

Comment: Above code should be done using javascript and html.

Comment: From where you want to bind the another combo box i mean to say from database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define array of data.
Each value of array will be the 
array itself . Than when the first combobox
changed you retrieve from data array 
your collection and build second combobox .